# python create multiple json objects

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build a list in Python as below. I want to call this function multiple times and build a json array, when i try with `json.dumps for p in range (0,10)` it adds extra `[]` for each json object

```
def buildlist():
   objects_list = []
   d = collections.OrderedDict()
   d['batteryLevel'] = random.randint(0, 100)
   d['firmwareVersion'] = "2016-04-16-ENGG"
   d['macId'] = MACprettyprint(randomMAC())
   d['name'] = "".join([random.choice(string.digits+string.letters) for i in xrange(7)])
   d['rssi'] = random.randint(0, 100) * -1
   d['status'] = random.choice([OPEN, LOCKED])
   objects_list.append(d)
   return objects_list
```

Comment: Please, do add how you are using this function within your code and where is the `json` part???...Your question does not fulfill the requirements for a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is. But the function you posted will always return a list containing just a single OrderedDict. Why don't you just return the OrderedDict and build the list outside the function?

```
def builditem():
   d = collections.OrderedDict()
   d['batteryLevel'] = random.randint(0, 100)      
   ...
   d['status'] = random.choice([OPEN, LOCKED])
   return d

json.dumps([builditem() for n in range(10)])
```

Comment: that was sweet, thanks a lot, worked like charm, hate myself when i realize why didn't i think of this simple

Comment: Try to make each function do just a single thing if possible. Your code will be more readable and easier to debug, test, reuse and maintain.